# SoundCloud API: search for more results after limit

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

Given

```
  http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=APIKEY&q=madonna&limit=2
```

There is any way to set limit 0,2 to get results form 0 to 2
or 
eg. limit 2,4 to get results form 2 to 4?

Answer (score 1):

the parameter is `offset`

eg.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?limit=10&offset=10&client_id=xxx

result: all songs from 10 to 20
```

Comment: offset seems to stop working after 300 even if more results are available